# Code=53 "Simulator verification failed."

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild

Since I updated to XCode 6.2, when I try to run

```
xcodebuild -project Demo.xcworkspace -scheme Demo clean build test
```

I'm always getting:

```
iPhoneSimulator: SimVerifier returned: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=53 
"Simulator verification failed." UserInfo=0x7f82b9e091a0 
{
    NSLocalizedFailureReason=A connection to the simulator verification service could
    not be established., 

    NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Ensure that Xcode.app is installed on a volume with 
    ownership enabled., 

    NSLocalizedDescription=Simulator verification failed.
}
```

Has anyone encountered this?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Same issue here - I see it when I build Swift framework with Carthage. It is reproducible on both Xcode 6.2 and latest Xcode 6.3 beta

Comment: Simply restarting Macbook solved my problem

Answer (score 21):

Rather than simply delete the `/Library/Developer` directory, I updated the permissions on all instances of `dyld_sim` to match those that Jeremy from Apple mentions in [this post](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1125867#1125867).  First, find all instances of this on your machine with the following command:

```
sudo find / -name dyld_sim
```

Then, check the permissions for each one:

```
ls -l "<file location\file name>"
```

If you don't see:

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel
```

Then you will need to modify the permissions to match properly.  In my case, the group ownership was wrong and listed as `admin` instead of `wheel`.  Using

```
sudo chown :wheel "<file location\file name>"
```

to change the group ownership on each of the incorrect instances corrected the issue.  If the issue is the flags and not ownership you will need to use `chmod` instead.

Comment: My variation: `find /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator -name dyld_sim -ls` to check ownership; `sudo find /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator -name dyld_sim -exec chgrp wheel {} \;` to change ownership

Comment: Michael explains the problem nicely
@BobMazanec one liners solve the problem nicely

Answer (score 5):

After trying both running the simulator (as suggested by Jeremy Huddleston Sequoia) and removing the unavailable simulators (as suggested by pwc) I still was getting no love.

Jeremy suggested it was a permissions issue with dyld_sim. So I went looking for dyld_sim files. I found two, one in /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS 8.1.simruntime ... the other inside /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform ...

The 8.1 version under /Library/Developer was from October last year. Facing a reinstall I decided to **remove the /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator directory** (which only contained a profile for the 8.1 simulator) and see what happened.

All good. Carthage now builds correctly for me.

My assumption is that Xcode build was getting a little lost and picking up the old one. SO nothing to do with permissions or unavailable simulators in my case.

Comment: Thank you. After removing the `/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator` directory, it works well now.

Comment: This fixed it for me as well. I had a leftover 7.1 simulator data.

Comment: An old 8.1 simulator profile at 2.5GB was the culprit for me. Permissions were fine however. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I was running into the same issue when trying to run `carthage` to build a 3rd-party library.

The error I was getting was:

```
2015-04-22 02:16:17.468 xcodebuild[944:9962] [MT] iPhoneSimulator: SimVerifier returned: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=53 "Simulator verification failed." UserInfo=0x7ffb237cf260 {NSLocalizedFailureReason=A connection to the simulator verification service could not be established., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Ensure that Xcode.app is installed on a volume with ownership enabled., NSLocalizedDescription=Simulator verification failed.}
```

I was reading [a thread on the Apple Developer Forum](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/264762?start=25&tstart=0) and decided to check the simulators I had installed via:

```
xcrun simctl list
```

Doing so found a lot of simulators that were unavailable:

```
-- Unavailable: com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-8-0 --
    iPhone 4s (E4B99ABA-C455-4579-AFB6-9FFE4D7B2D9B) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
    iPhone 5 (F4C1E6D1-102A-4E49-B8CB-6274258C8E55) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
    iPhone 5s (33C6AA80-EA85-41E8-928D-38598B87BBCB) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
    iPhone 6 Plus (293C225D-02C8-4458-BAEE-0F5ED76E308E) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
    iPhone 6 (C93CCB55-1DFB-4452-876D-663A8E85CBB8) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
    iPad 2 (DFC56B19-82F4-4587-95F5-E53154681689) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
    iPad Retina (AC5F3C69-9554-4A0A-84A7-81C586E7F0EC) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
    iPad Air (BD6C1EEB-9BCE-47BF-AC80-BD1AEFC61E06) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
    Resizable iPhone (37FBC485-B844-42DE-B77D-02995176E057) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
    Resizable iPad (B45EC16E-DB4D-4B0E-B969-90F468B673DA) (Shutdown) (unavailable, runtime profile not found)
```

I deleted each of the unavailable simulators via:

```
xcrun simctl delete [UUID]
```

(I copied that output from above and pasted into a text editor, deleted everything but the UUIDs, and prefixed each line with `xcrun simctl delete`.)

After doing that, I was able to run `carthage` without error.

Comment: Deleting unavailable simulators is completely unrelated to the issue here.  The only relevant thing that changed was that *something* connected to the service and thus made it such that the runtime was verified and permissions adjusted such that xcodebuild didn't need to on a subsequent run.  The deletion of the unavailable devices happened to do that as a side effect.  You could have also just run the iOS Simulator.app to fix the issue.

Comment: @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia Well, I tried everything in the Dev. Forum thread, including running the simulator. None of it worked. This did.

Comment: Well the only thing relevant is the ownership and permissions on dyld_sim.  The existence of older devices is not relevant to the issue.  If running the simulator app did not fix this for you, please file a radar and send me the radar number directly, so it doesn't get duped by someone to the xcodebuild issue.

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me. Super weird, but bravo @pwc

Answer (score 2):

Had the exact same problem. I managed to fix this by installing Xcode 6.3.1 (from AppStore), opening a project in Xcode and running it on the simulator.

After doing this I am now able to do the same using xcodebuild from the console. The error never went away though, but xcodebuild commands now work instead of remaining blocked.

Comment: Just tried that myself and, indeed, the error is still there but it's ignored and the build carries on. Is it then a XCode 6.2 issue?

Comment: Had the same issue on 6.3

Answer (score 0):

> sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/*

I then downloaded XCode from the developer website, instead of the app store, and reinstalled. This fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this problem was caused by conflict of command-line development tools and also due to Mac OS folder permission issues with the tools.

I was able to resolve it following these steps:

1. Quit any running instances of Xcode, Instruments and iOS simulators
2. Removing the developer folder: /Library/Developer
3. Remove all your Xcode installations: /Applications/Xcode.app,...
4. Reboot your Mac
5. Download Xcode.dmg from Apple Developer Portal (**NOT** from the App Store)
6. Reinstall Xcode
7. Launch Xcode

*Optionally*, though not the best thing to do, if you wanna install multiple versions of Xcode, make sure you activate the right Xcode version from **Xcode Preferences/Locations/Command-Line Tools**, before building your projects.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Run iOS Simulator.app, and it will connect to the verification service and fix ownership and permissions on dyld_sim such that xcodebuild doesn't need to.

Comment: What should the permissions be?

Comment: root:wheel ownership, 755 permissions

Answer (score 0):

Solution by @kevinoneill from https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/issues/424 helped me. Just removed the /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/ folder and no Xcode re-install was required anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the folder where you have your project and do the following:
chmod -R 777 ionic_test.

the problem is that you have root permission and xcode won't load files without permission.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change ownership mode for dclim files it may be happening that you are running Xcode tools directly from .dmg file instead of installed version. (If it is true Xcode appears on devices tag in finder)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem here. Running xcodebuild after lauching Xcode.app solved my problem. Mentioned by JeremyHu in this post https://devforums.apple.com/thread/264762?start=25&tstart=0